# Is there a Unicode Character to indicate possible linebreak in a string

Tags: unicode, language-agnostic

We are looking for a "BREAK NO-SPACE" character reverse to [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). It should not print anything, just indicate the components down the line, the word can be split and linebroken at these positions.

Is there anything similar to this in Unicode or any other encoding scheme? It would make life easier since we could then rely on built-in methods for line split in our framework instead of introducing custom logic and some "Magic Character".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Soft hyphen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) U+00AD is invisible but indicates where a word should be broken.

Comment: It seems this and the Zero Width Space have both unique advantages and disadvantages depending on system and language; see [this article](https://meiert.com/en/blog/word-division-on-word-break-soft-hyphens-and-zero-width-spaces/).

Answer (score 1):

So I found the [Zero Width Space](https://unicode.org/reports/tr14/#ZW) character `200B`. The documentation describes exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is a also "Zero Width Non-Joiner" (at 200C)

Comment: Zero Width Non-Joiner has no effect on line-breaking. Its only purpose is suppressing cursive joining.